# global secret token for soundcloud

Tags: javascript, private, soundcloud

to embed a sound via JS which is marked in soundcloud as "private", I need to add the secret_token parameter to the url. Now I have many sounds, some are private, some not. All ID's of them are stored in my database model. I am using a soundcloud-widget on my homepage and changing the sounditem dynamically via javascript. Easy. But I have to offer the possibility to every sounditem on my model, to add also the individual secret_token which then will be added to the url in the widget. This Seems a bit too much for me.

Isn't there a global secret_token for my soundcloud-account I can use instaed in the url? Please tell me there is a global token. And tell me where. :)

thanks, Falk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no "generic" secret token.

If you are gathering the information from the API and your program is acting as a signed in user you should be getting secret tokens on track representations from API requests – store this in your DB and apply them when generating the embed code.